# Borderline Audit question

Tags: support, review-audits

This morning I've failed an audit question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/11701119).

That's my first ban and it sounds harsh to me.

I do my review job very conscientiously, I do not hesitate to downvote and I flag everything that should.

For this particular answer I have hesitated. But after a while I considered it OK because it provides, although very basic, a possible answer to the question.

According to me, the only bad thing with my false assumption of this answer being "acceptable", is that this answer was incorrect.

I see no obvious reviewing mistake here.

Please explain me what I was supposed to do, and overall what is the mind process to arrive to the right action on this particular case.

Comment: I think you made the right decision, I also consider it an attempt at an answer. Bad audit indeed, although you could have edited the post to remove the fluff (not sure if that would have passed the audit or not).

Comment: Umm... indeed borderline - I've lifted the review ban in this case - just be wary - you don't get 2 days for a single audit failure.

Comment: I had another one some days ago, I can't remember on which one but it wasn't obvious either. as long as I was not banned I didnt care. But not now :p

Comment: and thank you @JonClements

Comment: @JonClements : for my own understanding of Meta, why do you flag the question as duplicate ?  Since it's a question about a specific review audit that was not reported yet. Is my question legitimate, should I have reported the issue differently, is there a way to ask for a lift ban differently? I prefer to ask because if it happened once, it will probably happen again :)

Comment: @ThomasG they're pretty much the same thing about failing audits in certain queues - so it's helpful for others that may look for information that they have multiple avenues of finding *one* of the questions and its resolution.

Comment: see [Dr. Strangedupe: Or, How I Learned to Stop Worrying And Love Duplication](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)